# Проблема с запросом Yii2

Tags: yii2

Проблема заключается в запросе поиска.

[image: Ошибка]

[image: Экшен]

yii\base\ErrorException: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php:361
Stack trace:

## 0 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php(361): yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleError(2, 'Invalid argumen...', 'C:\xampp\htdocs...', 361, Array)

## 1 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php(728): yii\db\Command->bindValues('name')

## 2 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\ActiveQuery.php(322): yii\db\Connection->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*)...', 'name')

## 3 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Query.php(456): yii\db\ActiveQuery->createCommand(Object(yii\db\Connection))

## 4 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\ActiveQuery.php(340): yii\db\Query->queryScalar('COUNT(*)', Object(yii\db\Connection))

## 5 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Query.php(347): yii\db\ActiveQuery->queryScalar('COUNT(*)', Object(yii\db\Connection))

## 6 C:\xampp\htdocs\controllers\CategoryController.php(40): yii\db\Query->count()

## 7 [internal function]: app\controllers\CategoryController->actionSearch()

## 8 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)

## 9 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)

## 10 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(528): yii\base\Controller->runAction('search', Array)

## 11 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(103): yii\base\Module->runAction('category/search', Array)

## 12 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(386): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))

## 13 C:\xampp\htdocs\web\index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()

## 14 {main}

Comment: То что вы передаете в функцию bindValues не является массивом. Для более полного ответа нужно знать детали, что вы делаете. А так не очень ясно

Comment: Производится поиск продуктов в базе данных через форму. Вот еще ниже ошибка, которая выдает.  ![Код ошибки](https://imgur.com/OZKYOoE).

Comment: Какой текст ошибки? Видно только строчку кода

Comment: ![Код ошибки](https://imgur.com/nWqW3ef).

Comment: У вас в функцию Command::bindValues передается строка "name", в то время, когда эта функция ожидает массив. К сожалению не весь стектрайс. И еще интересует, что за SQL запрос, его к сожалению тоже видно не полностью

Comment: Если Вы про запрос, то он вот в таком виде [Запрос SQL](https://imgur.com/6bX0jZn) Прикрепил полный стектрайс к посту

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы передаете неверные параметры в метод `where()`, [метод](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#where()-detail) должен принимать два параметра.

Правильный вариант:

```
$productsCategory = Product::find()->where(['like', 'name', $q])->asArray();
```